# In Qt/C++ how to turn on keyboard Capslock and Insert with leds?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm working on a virtual keyboard and want the actual hardware keyboard leds to turn on/off with when the virtual software keyboard Capslock, Insert buttons are pressed.

The code is in C++/Qt on running on Linux.

- Sorry didn't mean Insert led

Comment: From Qt, you can't. You can't even get the current caps lock status, let alone *setting* it. For cross platform, AFAIK there's no common access, so you need to rely on the OS native libraries and capabilities which may or may not provide that possibility (there should be some Python modules that allow an abstraction for most systems, though). Also, the common standard only has 3 leds, all of the leading to specific *lock* statuses: NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock. I don't know what you mean by "Insert button", but AFAIR there's no such led for that.

Comment: Besides, any of the above will probably only control the led status, not the keyboard status, which may be faked. The keyboard led may still show a "caps lock" active, but it will not change the result. You have to consider that keyboard input is mapped from a native scan code that may be set (or virtualized) either internally or externally by the driver, and the OS may still ignore that based on its own mappings. Long story short: even if you can access the led of a keyboard, nothing grants you that what was typed on that keyboard will actually match the result anyway.

Comment: You can try with Linux `setleds` command [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds)

Comment: Solution was to use xdotool, but we have to execute it from the source, probably using QProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Someone used used xdotool and it worked, but we have to execute it from the source code, probably using QProcess.